# Hermitian $Matrix > 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given $P ∈ C^{nxn}$ is a Hermitian matrix, prove or disprove that if $P ≥ 0$ and $P ≠ 0$, then $P > 0$.  I've been trying to answer this question, but to no avail.  The answer seems obvious, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Comment: You're not going to get much a response with the question as it is.  What work have you done on the problem.  What are your thoughts about the problem?

Comment: Do you think the answer is yes or no?

Comment: The way I see it is that the question is asking if given a positive semidefinite Hermitian matrix that is also known to be a nonzero matrix, then it can be said that the Hermitian matrix is positive definite.  At first from algebraic inequalities I thought the obvious answer would be yes, by definition, but now I'm thinking in terms of matrix inequalities that the not equal to zero part is saying that the matrix not a zero matrix, which means some entries in the Hermitian matrix could be zero, making it not positive definite and thus disproving the statement.

Comment: Does maybe $P\neq 0$ encode the fact that $P$ is nonsingular? In this case, the answer is yes. Otherwise, there is a plenty of nonzero positive semidefinite matrices if $n>1$.

Answer (score 1):

Reading your comment (which should be part of the question, by the way), I can tell you you are on the right track.

Another **hint**: try to find a counterexample with a diagonal matrix.